# previewActionItems() removed in Xcode Beta 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

I just updated my Xcode to newest version of the Xcode 8 beta.
Now I opened one Project I'm currently working on.

I seems, that the method to register previewQuickActions has changed, because I get a error for overriding this, that it conflicts with a objc getter.

```
func previewActionItems() -> [UIPreviewActionItem] {
    return ctrl.previewActionItems
}
```

I did some research on the internet, but did find any method to use or to implement to register previewActions.

I hope you can help me.

With regards
Chromo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd better see [an official documentation of `previewActionItems`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621408-previewactionitems).

> Declaration
>
> ```
> var previewActionItems: [UIPreviewActionItem] { get }
> ```

(Some documentations may not be up to date, as Swift is changing too swift. But this description seems to be catching up beta 4.)

Try this:

```
override var previewActionItems: [UIPreviewActionItem] {
    return ctrl.previewActionItems
}
```

It may be hard to find with some simple keyword searches, but there are many similar articles in Stack Overflow...

Comment: thanks for your answer, i was confused by the read-only modifier. And by the fact that i didn't know that you can override computed properties :)